# Pluto theme wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I want to insert a clickable link in main template.index template that will redirect to one of my pages in the JavaScript button at the top in Pluto theme. The text is there, but when you click it, it does not redirect you but opens up what I don't want.

Here's my code:

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-rel="#homepage_wrapper" id="expand_button" <?php
    if(empty($pp_display_hide_homepage)) {
        echo 'style="display:block;"';
    }
?>>
    <p style="color: #402D1F; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; ">
        <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/icon_arrow_right.png" alt="" id="arrow_picture"/>
        Click here for more info
    </p>
</a>
```

That click, for more information, I want it to be a clickable link which redirects me to another page in wordpress.

Comment: you have text, but you haven't give any link to that, then how could it redirect..? it should be like this .
<a href="redirection link">Click here for more info</a>

Answer (score 0):

A normal Html link looks like this:

```
<a href="yourUrl">link text</a>
```

It looks like you have an image tag in your link, so then it should look like this:

```
<a href="yourUrl"><img src="/images/icon_arrow_right.png" alt="" id="arrow_picture" />link text</a>
```

Comment: look at my website here http://chillaz.co.za....above in the click for more information. I want to be clickable and redirect to franchise opportunity page not the pop up that comes out...I can only edit it in main template index.php..So when I entere <a href="url"> click for more more information</a>...the text disappears. original code is above...I think maybe it's the ahref of the javascript that's disturbing it..I don't know, please help me